# Dispatching Index() from NEST into to Elasticsearch.NET failed

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am having error when calling `client.Index` when using Nest and Elasticsearch.NET

```
var httpConnection = new AwsHttpConnection(new AwsSettings
{
    AccessKey = "AKIAIFIV4LN6XZAFVX7Q",
    SecretKey = "MySecretKey",
    Region = "us-east-1",
});

var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri(sSearchURI));
var config = new ConnectionSettings(pool, httpConnection);
var client = new ElasticClient(config);
var person = new Person
{
    Id = "1",
    Firstname = "Martijn",
    Lastname = "Laarman"
};
var index = client.Index(person);
```

> Dispatching Index() from NEST into to Elasticsearch.NET failed
>   Received a request marked as PUT This endpoint accepts POST,PUT The
>   request might not have enough information provided to make any of
>   these endpoints:
>     - /{index}/{type}
>     - /{index}/{type}/{id}

Any idea?

Comment: It seems it cannot infer either the index or the type information. Just to test this theory, can you try the more explicit way: `client.Index(person, i => i.Index("persons").Type("person").Id(person.Id));` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the default index:

```
settings.DefaultIndex("indexName");
```